# Check given number is prime or not, if it is prime then find factorial of that number, if it is not prime then print sum-of-digit of that number

Tags: python

The sum of digit is running well, but Why is the factorial section not working? Is there any mistakes that I made with the if else, or the break ?

```
NUM = int (input ("Enter a number "))
if NUM > 1:
    for x in range (2, NUM):
        if (NUM % x) == 0:  
            temp = NUM
            sod = 0
            while temp > 0:
                remainder = temp % 10  
                sod += remainder
                temp = temp//10
            print (sod)
        break
    else:
        factorial = 1
        for I in range (1, NUM + 1,1):
            factorial *= I
        print (factorial)        
else:
    temp = NUM
    sod = 0
    while temp > 0:
        remainder = temp % 10  
        sod += remainder
        temp = temp//10
    print (sod)
```

Comment: Can you please provide *exactly* what the output, and *exactly* what the expected output should be?

Comment: You can also use the `math.factorial` function from the standard library, no need to write it yourself

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm still unfamiliar with using stack overflow, this is my first question posted, is there any way that I can show you the output ? or I just type it out

Comment: Yes, just edit the question and copy-paste it it. Post the full output but annotate the specific lines that you think are incorrect

Comment: so the factorial number is for the prime number, it works when I insert 2, but it somehow won't work with 3

Comment: What is the result if the number is 3? Please edit your answer to include that information

Comment: You probably meant for the `break` to be indented inside the `if`. As you wrote the code the break will always happen the first time through the loop.

Comment: I can't edit the post, it's pending. I tried to use math.factorial, but it won't work as well.

Comment: is it possible for you to write it out ? the question was given in the title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# example of factorial with prime numbers    
num = int(input("Enter a number"))
    factorial = 1
    if num%2 == 0:
        for i in range(1, num + 1):
            factorial = factorial*i
        print("The factorial of ",num," is",factorial)
```

Below code checks if the number is prime or odd number. if its prime it finds the factorial of that number and if its odd number then it sums the range of the number. Hope its what you were looking for.

```
NUM = int(input("Enter number here"))
if NUM > 0:
    if NUM % 2 == 0:
        factorial = 1
        for i in range(1, NUM +1):
            factorial = factorial*i
        print(factorial)
    else:
        sum_of_NUM = 0
        for x in range(NUM+1):
            sum_of_NUM += x
        print(sum_of_NUM)
else:
    print("something you want to put")
```

Comment: I like your desire to write code, but right now we want to help Jackson find the problems in his own code. It is important that he understands.

Comment: Next time I will think of that. Thanks for the heads up. 

Comment: Appreciate your code, the only mistake I made was just the indentation problem for the break @themadpsychologist

Comment: @LacksonMunthali Yeap, I will be more careful with the indentation. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

Your `break` statement on line 12 is outside the `if` statement, so the `for` loop will break after the first pass regardless of the value of `NUM`. Are you sure you didn't mean to indent the `break` another four spaces?

Comment: Thanks for the help ! That's really a minor mistake : (

Comment: @JacksonTai Not a problem. If your problem is solved, you'll want either to mark the correct answer as received (if you think your question will help others in the future) or delete the question (if you do not think it will help others). That way, people won't keep checking it to see how they can help.

Comment: ok, thanks for letting me know that @themadpsychologist